# How to configure jmeter to test a secured java rest api

Tags: java, api, rest, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a few APIs on which I need to perform load testing, 
The API has a auth token in the header and a request body with a reasonably big payload  which will vary with the user.
If I have to simulate 100 different users,
 how do i create a sampler for 100 diff users with 100 diff params?
Is CSV the only way out?

PS: I am a newbie wrt to jmeter

Comment: yes, CSV is the way to go and then you have to pass these values to the appropriate header

Comment: Is it possible to have two different config set ? one for header and one for payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used JMeter to test REST API. I have given detailed steps here.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/how-to-test-rest-api-using-jmeter/

Comment: If I have to configure a functional test. For example. place an order, then cancel the same order, then view the orders etc.. Can we sequence the scenarios? do you have any tutorial for that? I see there is an option called logiccontrooler. Just wanted to know if there is a tutorial you made for that

Comment: @user5118993, i do not have any tutorial for that. The scenario you look for can be done easily in JMeter. You need to use 'Regular Expression Extractor' to parse the response & get the text you want to send along with the next request. Please google it. In case of issues, raise your question here.